# Error is saying the dotnetcore 3.0 SDK does not support netstandard 2.1

Tags: .net, .net-core, dotnet-publish

I am doing a docker build with a RUN step that does a `dotnet publish`. The error appears to indicate that dotnetcore 3.0 does not support netstandard2.1 (which is incorrect according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

Why am I getting this error?

```
$ docker build -t Blah/api -f ./Blah.Api/Dockerfile --build-arg Blah_version=0.0.0 --build-arg Blah_build_num=${buildNum} .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  32.78MB

Step 1/14 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:3.0-sdk AS build-env
 ---> a4b0ceb74bae
...
...
Step 6/14 : RUN dotnet restore ./Blah.Api/Blah.Api.csproj  && dotnet publish ./Blah.Api/Blah.Api.csproj --no-restore --configuration=Release --framework=netcoreapp3.0 /p:AssemblyVersion=${Blah_version}.${Blah_build_num} --output=/app/out
 ---> Running in e1f8563f8bf3
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100-preview-010184/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(155,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Standard 2.1.  Either target .NET Standard 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Standard 2.1. [/app/Blah.Integration.Chains/Blah.Integration.Chains.csproj]
```

Comment: Looks like you're using the first preview.  I don't think the first preview supported .net standard 2.1.  Use the most recent preview (8 i believe) instead

Comment: 3.0.100-preview-010184 was indeed from 2018, the used container was not pulled and I think the new ones are in the Microsoft container registry

Comment: Well crap. Why does 3.0 tag go to the oldest preview? That is silly

Comment: Looks like they're on preview9 as of 5 minutes ago, haha. Oh dear this is fun stuff

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3270